# Drawing a curved border-right in a box using CSS3

Tags: image, css, border, css-shapes

How can I draw a border-right in a box using CSS3 like in this image?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I totally agree with you but sometimes OP has no clue how to implement something especially for CSS shapes.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be this,

```css
#curve{
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    border-top-right-radius:50px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}
    
#curve:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="curve"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

SVG is much better option to create such kind of shapes. It is simple and scale able.

We can use SVG's `path` element to create this shape and fill it with some color, gradient or pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in path element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Below is the necessary code to create this shape:

```
<path d="M10,10
         L210,10
         Q230,10 250,50
         T290,90
         L10,90
         Z" />
```

I've used 5 commands inside `path` element. Below is a brief description:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `L` command is used to draw straight lines.
- `Q` command is used to draw curves.
- `T` produces the same type of curve as earlier, but if it follows another `Q` command or a `T` command.
- `Z` command is used to close the current path.

**Output:**

[image: Output Image]

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(#466273, #5c8ea8) no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
  <path d="M10,10 L210, 10 Q230,10 250,50 T290,90 L10,90 Z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="yellowgreen" />
</svg>
```

---

**Useful Resources:**

- SVG: [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)